# Django save_form() calculating with inlines

Tags: django

I Have a setup like this:

**models.py**

```
class BargainItem(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Item)
    bargain = models.ForeignKey(Bargain)
    quantity = models.IntegerField()

class Bargain(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    discount_price = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2)
    total_price = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, editable=False, default=Decimal(0))

class Item(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    price = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2)
```

**admin.py**

```
class BargainItemInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = BargainItem
    extra = 1

class BargainAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    model = Bargain
    # ...
    inlines = (BargainItemInline,)

    def save_formset(self, request, form, formset, change):
        instances = formset.save(commit=False)
        for instance in instances:
            if isinstance(instance, Bargain):
                # ...
                instance.save()
```

somehow update total_price to the Bargain object
total_price = (instance.quantity * instance.product.price) - DISCOUNT

I am trying to update the total_price for the bargain after the bargainItems are saved but BEFORE writing to the db... I'm puzzled

Answer (score 0):

I think in this case, you're going to have to use a custom signal that updates the field after the Bargain is saved. Using post_save on the Bargain object won't work, because you'll get into an infinite loop if you're saving the Bargain object in a post_save signal.

Overriding the save_model method of the BargainAdmin won't work, because the inline models won't be saved until after the Bargain is saved.

Hope that gets you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

This works on mysql but on sqlite3 I get a does not exists and it instances returns an empty list... ??

```
    def save_formset(self, request, form, formset, change):
      #instances = formset.save(commit=False)
      #bargain_id = 0
      total_price = Decimal(0)
      print("Formset: ", formset)
      instances = formset.save(commit=False)
      print("Instances: ", instances)
      bargain_id = 0

      for instance in iter(instances):
          if isinstance(instance, BargainProduct):
              total_price += instance.quantity * instance.product.price
              bargain_id = instance.id
          instance.save()
      updateTotal = Bargain.objects.get(id=bargain_id)
      updateTotal.total_price = total_price - updateTotal.discount_price
      updateTotal.save()
```